# Load ZUL from Jar

Tags: java, zk, zul

anyone know how to load a Zul from a Jar?
I have a library project wich contains Zul.
currently i use createComponents(String uri, Component parent, Map arg) but i don't know or can't reference a uri in a jar.

---

I use now:

```
public static Component createComponentsFromJar(final String path, final Component parent, final Map<?,?> arg) throws IOException {
    final InputStream resourceAsStream = ComponentHelper.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
    final PageDefinition pageDefinition = Executions.getCurrent().getPageDefinitionDirectly(new InputStreamReader(resourceAsStream), "zul");
    resourceAsStream.close();
    return Executions.createComponents(pageDefinition, parent, arg);
}
```

does any know some problems with this method of creating new pages? Some binding problems or someting?

Comment: Why You are mixing web project with Pure java coding i never saw this type of coding

Comment: I made a dynamically wizard, you can add pages to the wizard like:
pages.add(new WizardPageConfig(SOMEID, "/pages/personWizard/pageStart.zul")); this wizard logic is in our framework and the file upload page for the wizard is a default zul, wich should be in the framework too.

Comment: is this fiddle kind of thing?

Comment: i cant fiddle that cause i think fzkfiddle does not support usage of jars :D

Comment: @subodh this is a very common way of creating components in the ZK framework, you can see an example in [ImageLabel.java here](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/composite/composite_component). Kani, this is a very good question. I hope you get an answer, I'll be putting some thought into it.

Comment: @Sean can you please let me know where in composite Component we need to add ZUL file inside Jar file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Executions.createComponents will work with ZK Specific URI (refer to [Inter-Application Communication](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Communication/Inter-Application_Communication)) where "~./*" in ZK Specific URI will get the file under "classpath/web/*", assume your zul page under "src/web/zul/pages" as below:

[image: zul page under src]

And you export the src folder as a jar, then you can create component with the zul file in jar as below:

```
Executions.createComponents("~./zul/pages/zulInJar.zul", parent, null);
```